# Get a TextView to scroll

Tags: nativescript

I've got a TextView inside a GridLayout and have it set to take maximum available height. That works.

But If the user presses new-line to the bottom of the TextView and more - the TextView cursor goes off the bottom of the screen instead of scrolling the TextView.

How can I get the TextView to scroll.

Comment: You could use ScrollView - https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/scroll-view and add the TextView inside it, however it would help if you could give us sample code, where the problem could be reproduced locally then we will be able to provide better solution for your case.

Comment: Here's the xml file. `<GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto,*">  

            <GridLayout row="0" col="0" columns="auto,*" rows="auto">
                <Label text="header" row="0" col="0" />
            </GridLayout>

            <GridLayout row="1" col="0" columns="auto,*" rows="auto">
                <Label text="Note" row="0" col="0" />
                <ScrollView row="0" col="1">
                    <TextView text="{{ note }}" hint="Enter text..." />
                </ScrollView>
            </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>`. No scrolling.

Comment: is it iOS or Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `iOS` the `TextVie`w should be scrollable by default if you set large text in it.
However for `Android` you could use `ScrollView` and to use `StackLayout` for main container inside it. For further help you could review the below attached example:

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto,*"> 
    <GridLayout row="0" col="0" columns="auto,*" rows="auto"> 
      <Label text="header" row="0" col="0" /> 
    </GridLayout> 

    <GridLayout row="1" col="0" columns="auto,*" rows="auto"> 
      <Label text="Note" row="0" col="0" /> 
      <ScrollView orientation="vertical" row="1" col="0" height="300" width="300" backgroundColor="green">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="scroll-menu" backgroundColor="red">
                <TextView text="" hint="Enter text..." /> 
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout> 
  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! it also works w/o setting the height and width explicitly in ScrollView - but then for the GridLayout you have to set rows to * - which makes sense.